# downcast with string

Tags: c#, class, casting, type-conversion

I have a problem with downcasting, how do I convert the string "Label" to the class type Label for casting and is it possible to reach the 'Texts' class?

```
public class GFXObject
{
   // Constructor etc...
}
public class Label : GFXObject
{
    public Texts Text = new TextClass();

    // Constructor etc...
}

public class Button : GFXObject
{
    // Constructor etc...
}

public class Texts
{
    public string Text = "empty";

    // Constructor etc...
}

// My List of objects
Dictionary<string, GFXObject> objects;

// Disregarding any troubleshooting
public void ChangeText(string classtype, string name, string text)
{
    // How do I convert the string classtype to a ClassType
    ((classtype)objects[name]).Text.Text = text;

    // If parameters would be equal to "Label", "label", "changed":
    // ((Label)objects["label"].Text.Text = "changed";
}
```

Is it possible to use the ChangeText function if extended or modified?

Comment: `((Label)objects["label1"]).Text = "changetext"`

Comment: The question is how do I convert the string "Label" to the class Label

Comment: You realize that if the objects collection contains a GFXObject object that isn't of the type Label (which is allowable), the cast cannot work.

Comment: Updated for some clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that only via reflection:

```
public void ChangeText(string classtype, string name, string text)
{
    var type = Type.GetType(classtype);
    type.GetProperty("Text").SetValue(objects[name], text);
}
```

Please note that `classtype` needs to be an assembly-qualified name if the method is in a different assembly than the type. If it is in the same assembly it needs to be fully qualified, i.e. including the namespace.

If that's a problem, you could get rid of the `classtype` parameter and use this method:

```
public void ChangeText(string name, string text)
{
    var type = objects[name].GetType();
    type.GetProperty("Text").SetValue(objects[name], text);
}
```

Another possibility would be to make use of the DLR and the `dynamic` keyword:

```
public void ChangeText(string name, string text)
{
    dynamic item = objects[name];
    item.Text = text;
}
```

Please note that every code that uses the dynamic `item` variable is evaluated only at runtime. This means that this code compiles even if there is no `Text` property on that particular item. It will then throw an exception at runtime.

---

Having said all that, the *correct* solution to this problem would be to introduce a base class or interface that holds the `Text` property.

Comment: Another question is, how would I got about if I wanted to change the 'Texts' class variables?

Comment: @lek0: I don't understand the question in your comment. What do you mean when you say you want to *change*  the class variable?

Comment: Let's say I have Type type = objects[name].GetType(). Is it possible to use it as described in the function ChangeText in any way?

Comment: That could work, another question would be, is it possible to take the 'var type = objects[name].GetType()' and use it in a way like this -> ((type)objects[name]).Text.Text = "newtext" i some kind of way? So that I could access the variables directly instead of using GetProperty and SetValue.

Comment: @lek0: No, that's impossible. But you can utilize the `dynamic` keyword. See third code sample.

Comment: With all these options in front of me, I still feel just like you say, it would be wisest to introduce a base class or interface. It has been of great help and I thank you greatly for it.

Comment: @lek0: You are welcome. BTW: On SO it is general consent that you should accept the answer that helped you the most - if you want to accept an answer at all. If the answer you currently accepted indeed helped you most, everything is fine. Otherwise you might think about changing that.

Comment: Ah, thought I could accept both :). Well, then I stand corrected.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution, if the amount of classes being used is small, could be to create a helper to set the property, like:

```
public void ChangeText(string classtype, string name, string text)
{
    switch(classtype)
    {
       case "ClassType1":
          ((ClassType1)objects[name]).Text = text;
          break;
       case "ClassType2":
          ((ClassType2)objects[name]).Text = text;
          break;
       etc...
       default:
          throw new InvalidOperationException("ClassType {0} is not supported", classtype); 
}
```

Comment: This is the solution I have right now, but with multiple GFXObject subclasses holding the same information It will become a lot of code. Just wondered if there's any smarter solution.